# Linking to lua libraries w/ codeblocks on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, ide, lua

After I downloaded the source for lua, I followed the install instructions, doing...

`make linux install`
`make generic install`

I've also done the `make test` and it passes, printing out `Hello World, from Lua 5.1`.

However, I can't link to the lua libraries in CodeBlocks. I know where lualib.a is (usr/local/lib) which I set in my Search Directories for the linker. I still get error messages like...

`undefined reference to lua_isstring`

Am I missing something critical here?

P.S. I had this running on Windows via Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Linking directly to the library rather than specifying the directory it was in worked.

Comment: You can mark your own anser as accepted. Although you don't earn reputation, in case of people searching for this same problem they will know there is a solution even before entering this thread. And welcome to SU!